# How can I add my website domain URL here like this "slider.ai" and also a "Featured" badge on the Chrome Web Store extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, plugins, manifest.json, chrome-web-store

[image]

I developed an extension and would like to showcase my website's domain name on the Chrome Web Store page, similar to the slider screenshot above provided, for users to easily install my extension.I believe featuring my website's domain name prominently on the Chrome Web Store page will help users recognize and trust the source of the extension. This will not only enhance the overall user experience but also increase the credibility of my extension among potential users.By showcasing my website's domain name on the Chrome Web Store page, users will have a clear indication of where the extension is coming from, providing transparency and reassurance. This can help build a stronger connection between my website and the extension, ultimately leading to higher user engagement and satisfaction. Additionally, featuring the domain name prominently can also help drive traffic to my website, increasing visibility and potentially attracting new users. Overall, incorporating my website's domain name on the Chrome Web Store page is a strategic move that can benefit both the extension and my website in the long run.